# Can we Connect On premis Oracle server using Azure hosted IR into DataFactory and use it as a Source and sink?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Here is my situation ,

My Org Oracle server is onpremis .

I wanted to connect it as a source and sink in my Datafactory using Azure Hosted IR .

People recommended to use Self Hosted IR .

But I wanted to use Azure Hosted IR.

Can we do that ? I found some documentation but its not helpful.

Can anyone clearly depict how to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is within a vnet would be accessible to Azure data factory via a bridge that links both the ADF and the object and that bridge is what is the self hosted IR.
So basically you would have to create a server within the same vnet as the database and set up self IR on that server and leverage it in ADF to access that database(both as a source or sink) since it would be a common linked service.

https://www.techbrothersit.com/2022/01/how-to-install-self-hosted-integration.html

Comment: So you are saying its not possible through Azure hosted IR?

Comment: In case if you make your server accessible from public without any firewall etc, you can access it from Azure IR but it would be a great security vulnerability